# Reducing featureCollection by using group in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Suppose I have a `featurecollection`, including two `aa`.

How can I reduce (maybe other functions) the featurecollection by calculate the mean value of `aa`?

**Before**

```
 var features = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(11, 22), {name: 'aa',value:10}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(33, 44), {name: 'bb',value:20}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(11, 22), {name: 'aa',value:30}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(55, 66), {name: 'cc',value:40})
];
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
```

**After**

```
var features = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(11, 22), {name: 'aa',value:20}), // (10+30)/2
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(33, 44), {name: 'bb',value:20}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(55, 66), {name: 'cc',value:40})
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to itirate over the unique identifier, name in your case. and filter all features that match it, compute the mean and overwrite it. This should do the trick:

```
var reduce = fromList.distinct('name')

var uniqueNames = reduce.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ['name']).values().get(0)

var iterate = ee.List(uniqueNames).map(function(n){
  var filt = fromList.filter(ee.Filter.eq('name', n)) 
  // mean
  var mean = filt.aggregate_mean('value')
  
  // overwrite
    return ee.Feature(filt.first().set('value', mean));
  
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2307664929ac4485abc1c8708c5e3d6f